# How to reset Oauth authentication approval with Express.js and Passport.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, oauth-2.0, google-api, passport.js

I'm not sure how to reset Oauth authentication approval. I'm using Passport with the Google Oauth2 strategy. In my /logout route, I call `req.logOut()`. However, when I go to the authentication route afterwards, the Oauth authentication screen does not come up again; the previous authentication is reused and I am logged in automatically. How do I prevent this?

For context, here is my middleware:

```
    app.use(morgan('tiny', { skip: (req, res) => req.baseUrl === "/static" })) 
    app.use(express.urlencoded())
    app.use(express.json({ limit: "20mb" }))
    app.use(cookieParser())
    app.use(session({
        resave: false,
        store: new session.MemoryStore(),
        secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET || "abcd",
        cookie: { secure: false, maxAge: 1000 /*, httpOnly: false*/ },
        saveUninitialized: false
    }))

    const passport = configureAuthentication()
    app.use(passport.initialize(), passport.session())
```

And here is my current auth and logout routes:

```
    app.get('/auth/google', passport.authenticate('google', { scope: ["profile", "email"] }))
    app.get('/auth/google/callback',
        // function (req, res, next) { console.log(`Callback handling, req.user = ${req.user}`) },
        passport.authenticate('google'/*, { failureRedirect: '/auth/google' }*/),
        function (req, res) {
            // Successful authentication, redirect home.
            console.log(`Successful authentication,req.user = ${req.user}, redirecting to '/'`)
            res.redirect('/')
        }
    )

    app.get("/logout", (req, res, next) => {
        req.session.destroy(function (err) {
            if (err) console.error(err)
            return res.redirect('/')
        })
    })
```

And here is my passport configuration:

```
function configureAuthentication/*<U>*/(/*authProvider: AuthProvider<U>*/) {
    passport.serializeUser(((user: User, done: (err: any, user: User) => any) => {
        // console.log(`Serializing user ${JSON.stringify(user, undefined, 2)}`)
        done(null, user)
    }) as any)
    passport.deserializeUser((obj: User, done) => {
        console.log(`DeSerializing user ${JSON.stringify(obj, undefined, 2)}`)
        done(null, obj as any)
    })

    passport.use("google", new passportGoogleOauth20.Strategy(
        {
            clientID: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID!,
            clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET!,
            // callbackURL: `https://vytals.herokuapp.com/auth/google/callback`,
            // callbackURL: `http://localhost:${process.env.PORT || "49720"}/auth/google/callback`,
            callbackURL: '/auth/google/callback',
            scope: [
                // Per-file access to files created or opened by the app. 
                // File authorization is granted on a per-user basis and is revoked when the user deauthorizes the app.
                // scope: ``,
                'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file',

                // Allows access to the Application Data folder.
                'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata'

                // scope: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'],
            ]
        },

        function (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
            console.log(`User access token: "${accessToken}`)
            console.log(`User refresh token: "${refreshToken}`)
            console.log(`User profile: ${JSON.stringify(profile, undefined, 2)}`)

            // User.findOrCreate({ driveId: profile.id }, function (err: any, user: any) {
            //  return done(err, user)
            // })

            const user: User = {
                id: profile.id,
                displayName: profile.displayName,
                emailAddress: profile.emails && profile.emails.length > 0 ? profile.emails[0].value : undefined,
                imageUrl: profile.photos && profile.photos.length > 0 ? profile.photos[0].value : undefined,
                provider: "google",
                refreshToken,
                accessToken
            }
            return done(null, user)
        }
    ))

    return passport
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with this:

```
app.get('/logout', function (req, res){
    req.session.destroy(function() {
        res.clearCookie('connect.sid');
        res.redirect('/');
    });
});
```

Or you can create a function:

```
const eraseCookie = (name) => {
    document.cookie = `${name}=; Max-Age=-99999999;`;
};
```

And use it like:

```
eraseCookie('cookie-name')
```

Comment: @prmph Oh sorry, I updated the code. I wanted to write this.

Comment: @Vlahovljak Thanks, but it's still not working

Comment: @Can you check in the dev tools the name of the cookie, maybe it's not this name. I updated the answer too, at least you can implement a function to delete the cookie.

Comment: @ Vlahovljak the cookie is indeed called "connect.sid", I checked in the dev tools. But is not being cleared

Comment: @prmph Did you try with this function `eraseCookie('cookie-name')`?

Comment: @Vlahovljak your eraseCookie function does not work, because there is no 'document' on the server

Comment: @prmph I mean can you delete it on the client side? If nothing works.